# /etc/group sudo users definition does not match with /etc/sudoers.d/ on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sudo

I have defined a sudoers by writing a file in `/etc/sudoers.d/`, and it works well, but the user does not appear in the file `/etc/group` at the "sudo" line.
However the command `sudo -l -U <user>`
confirms the `<user>` is a sudoer (and the user herself confirmed she could do command with sudo).

Is this a normal behavior? Is there a way to update the file `/etc/group/` accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's normal.

The sudo group in Ubuntu is just provided as a convenient way to give users elevated privileges *without* having to add them in /etc/sudoers.d or edit the main /etc/sudoers file, since `%sudo` is already present as a sudo user in the default file:

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

There is no linkage between the sudo group and the `sudo` program beyond the name chosen for this group. Updating the sudo group to include your user as well would just result in multiple matches:

```
 When multiple entries match for a user, they are applied in order.  Where
 there are multiple matches, the last match is used (which is not neces‐
 sarily the most specific match).
```